# Prop. 2.3 Hartshorne: φ:A→B φ A B induces a morphism Spec(B)→Spec(A)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It is on page 73 Prop 2.3. I do not understand a step in the part(c). That is, if we have $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ and $Y=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$, given a morphism of local ringed space $(f,f^*):(Y,\mathcal{O}_Y)\to(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$, I know how to construct a homomorphism $A\to B$, say $\varphi$, and why $\varphi$ induces f, but I do not now why $\varphi$ induces $f^*$

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is this: once we know that $\varphi$ induces $f$, the commutative diagram at the bottom of p.73 precisely says that the morphism of sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} A} \to f_\ast\mathcal{O}_{\operatorname{Spec} B}$ induced by $\varphi$ is equal to  $f^\#$ on stalks.

Since a morphism of sheaves is determined on stalks, the result follows.

Comment: Oh get it. Thanks a lot!